# App was rejected by App Store because of IPV6 issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, app-store, ipv6

My app get rejected by app store because of IPV6 issues. Here is the information by App Store

> 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness Guideline 2.1 - Performance
>
> Your app crashed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1 connected to an IPv6
>   network when we:
>
> entered the provided credentials. The app loaded for a second and then
>   crashed. When relaunching the app it appears we’re stilled “logged in”
>   but the app loads for a moment and crashes again.
>
> This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - On Wi-Fi
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app and test it on a device
>   while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to
>   ensure that it runs as expected.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please
>   review Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash
>   Reports.
>
> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please review
>   Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem in iOS. Than I change my reachblility class internet connection method and my app approved. If You want to make Ipv6 network in your system than please check

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html
```

Objective c

```
+ (instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection
{
  struct sockaddr_in6 zeroAddress;
  bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
  zeroAddress.sin6_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
  zeroAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  return [self reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr *)  &zeroAddress];
}
```

Swift 3

```
 func ipv6Reachability() -> SCNetworkReachability? 
{
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
 zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
   zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)

   return withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
$0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
 }
 })
 }
```

Comment: Which is best your above swift3 code or code given below: 
`var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)`

Comment: Yes it will work. If IPV6 support than It will support IPv4

Comment: I have face this same issue, 5 times apple has rejected my app due to this reason. I have also upload an app video but still apple has rejected my app. 

My API is working wether code is 
struct sockaddr_in6 zeroAddress;
OR

struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;

(Due to shortage of characters, I have not written whole ipv4 or ipv6 code.)
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I too faced this issue before many times. Apple is now supporting only apps those are compatible with IPv6.

First I tested my application as per their description. I tested on IPv6 but I didn't get any error as they said. So first complete debugging after connecting to IPv6. If you feel, it's working fine then do this.

I found out the IPVersion of my network through different websites. I took screenshots of the network I connected to on mobile and sent those screen shots to apple for review(saying it's a proof of connecting to IPv6).

Here below are the couple of sites that help you in finding out which version you are using.

[Google IPv6 test](http://ipv6test.google.com/)

Now it's accepted

Answer (score 0):

Problem is I used some code to check whether app connected to internet or not. Those code supports only for IPV4 not for IPV6. so I just update those code to supporting IPV6. Here is the code:

Old code:

```
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
```

New code:

```
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)
```